# In my app,POST method is not working in axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have created a button in react js and on clicking it should do the POST method on the url using axios **https://149.129.128.3:5443/wcs/resources/store/1/guestidentity**

But, instead it is throwing me error.

[image]

But, the same url if I POSTMAN/ Api tester app, using POST method, I'm getting this response.

```
{
"personalizationID": "1540911564271-271",
"resourceName": "guestidentity",
"WCToken": "1283%2CxZaF%2B0sJC6%2B1iH7O1216DPA1lYNyfzA44ziA4Qn0xDY4TJWdHxUgetyqnU31dp1m5j02Ppumc55lRNLGiRpc9SNQmbTdLSkgfey5cig28PBXtqLNEa2od4Gy2g1OWQ%2Bo0uplGYkSpyLqAnpi3Fnb9DKfiJ8hLzJFDxUh3tpAIH72DupPU1BF59MfZ1qeXGhlpyL2Hcf60GSdpkzKRbJmTO2t2VrV2xNWO9arivV5TxM%3D",
"userId": "1283",
"WCTrustedToken": "1283%2C2XbylA4QPc%2B4NS3yjcscvmLmgY8BKSc%2Fy2b0z9%2BkFYQ%3D"
}
```

Below is my code for it:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: "",
      isLoading: false
    };
    this.click = this.click.bind(this);
  }

  click() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });

    axios
      .post(
        "https://149.129.128.3:5443/wcs/resources/store/1/guestidentity",
        {}
      )
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ data: response.data, isLoading: false });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.setState({ data: err, isLoading: false });
      });
  }
  render() {
    const name = this.state.data && this.state.data.name;
    return (

      <div>
        <button onClick={this.click} disabled={this.state.isLoading}>{'click me'}</button>
        {name}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Can someone please help me on this. I would be grateful if somebody could provide me an insight or guide me. I dont know where my code is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming here that `{this.state.data}` is an object, you cannot just throw an object into the react code and expect it to render.

If it's an array then consider doing something like in the render before the return, assuming your data is an array with each object having a name property:

```
let dataArray = this.state.data.map((item) => item.name);
```

then use `{dataArray}` in your code where you are using `{this.state.data}`

if it's an object with properties than you will need to find those out by maybe using a `console.log('data = ', this.state.data);` in your render before the return

then lets say this.state.data.name is a property you have, you can use that in the code, again in the render before the return:

```
const name = this.state.data && this.state.data.name;
```

then use {name} within the render to show the value.

Also another thing you can cleanup here is your button:

```
<button onClick={this.click} disabled={this.state.isLoading}>
      {' click me '}
</button>
```

Comment: the error has gone. but there is another error. I have updated the code in my question and also the screenshot. Will you take a look on it

Comment: That looks like something with your API certificate. I believe it was in the first screenshot as well. Your React Code looks fine to me. Should run fine if data.name exists in the data object returned from the API.

Comment: Have a look at: https://superuser.com/questions/1083766/how-do-i-deal-with-neterr-cert-authority-invalid-in-chrome hope that helps